# Google Chart API Implementation

Tags: charts, google-api, google-visualization

Am using google API to implement chart in my Project. Am using Scatter chart.
I need to implement chart like below. How can Achieve this.? Is there any other way to Achieve this by using any other Open source chart.?

[Sample Google Chart which I need](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5Aqc.png)

[Additional requirement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfqLs.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a [ComboChart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/combochart) to combine scatter and area series

the area series should be stacked
set the color of the first layer to `'transparent'`

use `null` for values where the series do not coincide

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'x');
  data.addColumn('number', 'area bottom');
  data.addColumn('number', 'area top');
  data.addColumn('number', 'scatter');
  data.addRows([
    [1.5, null, null, 1.5],
    [3, 3, 3, null],
    [6, 3, 3, null]
  ]);

  var options = {
    areaOpacity: 1,
    colors: ['transparent', '#ff9900', '#3366cc'],
    hAxis: {
      format: '#,##0.0',
      ticks: [0, 1.5, 3, 4.5, 6],
      title: 'FINAL SCORE'
    },
    height: 320,
    legend: {
      position: 'none'
    },
    isStacked: true,
    seriesType: 'area',
    series: {
      2: {
        type: 'scatter'
      }
    },
    title: 'Final Score',
    vAxis: {
      format: '#,##0.0',
      ticks: [0, 1.5, 3, 4.5, 6],
      title: 'FINAL SCORE'
    },
    width: 320
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(
    document.getElementById('chart_div')
  );
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

---

**UPDATE**

just add another area layer for the new requirement...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('number', 'x');
  data.addColumn('number', 'area bottom');
  data.addColumn('number', 'area middle');
  data.addColumn('number', 'area top');
  data.addColumn('number', 'scatter');
  data.addRows([
    [1.5, null, null, null, 1.5],
    [3, 3, 3, null, null],
    [4.5, 3, 3, null, null],
    [4.5, 3, 1.5, 1.5, null],
    [6, 3, 1.5, 1.5, null]
  ]);

  var options = {
    areaOpacity: 1,
    colors: ['transparent', '#ff9900', '#f8bbd0', '#3366cc'],
    hAxis: {
      format: '#,##0.0',
      ticks: [0, 1.5, 3, 4.5, 6],
      title: 'FINAL SCORE'
    },
    height: 320,
    legend: {
      position: 'none'
    },
    isStacked: true,
    seriesType: 'area',
    series: {
      3: {
        type: 'scatter'
      }
    },
    title: 'Final Score',
    vAxis: {
      format: '#,##0.0',
      ticks: [0, 1.5, 3, 4.5, 6],
      title: 'FINAL SCORE'
    },
    width: 320
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(
    document.getElementById('chart_div')
  );
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: thanks... really helps.. I have one more requirement in this. added additional screenshot. please view that.. can we make changes like this?

Comment: When I change ticks into [0, 1,2,3,4,5] in vAxis, I get extra grid lines like above screenshot(extra gridlines). How to rectify ? If I added gridlines count in both axis, no changes occur in Vaxis.